# How to set first option in Product And Custom Post type Dropdown CF7 wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am using wordpress plugin Product And Custom Post type Dropdown CF7 which allows us to show the products dropdown from Woocommerce. I want to add first option as 'select product'. How can I do that? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. It can be done as:

```
var data = {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Barn owl'
};

var newOption = new Option(data.text, data.id, false, false);
$('#mySelect2').append(newOption).trigger('change');
```

Comment: I had the same issue but I found now a better plugin, which has an option by default to use a first blank item: https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-post-fields/